# ViewModel has no properties set in Model using HttpPost Create method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, http-post

I have a simple MVC3 app with an EF4 Model

```
Log
.Name
.CreatedDate
.LogTypeId

LogTypes
.Id
.Description
```

and a ViewModel

```
LogViewModel
Log MyLog
List<SelectListItem> Options

LogViewModel(){
  Log = new Log();
}
```

This displays in my view correctly and I can edit/update the values, display the drop down list and set the name to "MyTestValue".

However, in my controller's HttpPost Create method the properties for logVm.Log are not set?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(LogViewModel logVm){
  logVm.Log.Name == "MyTestvalue"; //false - in fact its null
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you verified whether it's logVm or logVm.Log that is null?

Comment: logVm.Log is null, logVm is set correctly (I added a string property and this is still set in controller)

Comment: <to self>YOU MUPPET!</to self>  Simple really...the property in the Controller's method needs to be called "model"...obvious when you think about it!!!

Comment: True, I totally overlooked that :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller method should have a property named **model**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(LogViewModel **model**){
  **model**.Log.Name == "MyTestvalue"; //true    }
```

Answer (score 3):

That's probably because in your edit form you don't have corresponding values. So if yuor view is strongly typed to `LogViewModel` the form input names must be appropriately named:

```
@model LogViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Log.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Log.Name)
    </div>

    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Log.SomeOtherProperty)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Log.SomeOtherProperty)
    </div>

    ...

    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

sop that when the form is submitted the POSTed values look like this:

```
Log.Name=foo&Log.SomeOtherProperty=bar
```

Now the default model binder will be able to successfully bind your view model. Also make sure that the properties you are trying to assign are public and that have a setter.